# Cannot find -lglad

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to compile this piece of code using GCC:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(){
     return 0;
}
```

I am following this [guide](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Creating-a-window). As the guide said I went to https://glad.dav1d.de/ and generated glad. I placed the `glad` and `KHR` include folders in my `/usr/include` folder and placed `glad.c` in the folder where I have this piece of code.

This is the command I am trying to use to compile the code:

```
gcc test.cpp -o test -lglad -lglfw
```

I get this compile error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglad
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: add -L/path/to/libglad.so  to the command line?

Comment: Where would I find the file libglad.so?

Comment: run `locate libglad.so` or `find / -name libglad.so`?

Comment: I mean where would I find that online as, I have not downloaded any file called libglad.so, this is the github repo https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad

Comment: If they have a package for your platform - install it the way platform tells (for instance "apt-get install ..." on Ubuntu, "pacman -S ..." on Arch, etc.), if they don't - you would need to download their source code from github and compile/install yourself - that's usually the process.

Comment: I am on arch, and that is the first thing I checked I don't see any package called glad in the official repos or  the aur. According to the faq in the github you should be able to install it using just the webservice

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you can just  compile using

```
gcc test.cpp glad.c -o test -lglfw
```